# Combinatorial definition of Hall–Littlewood polynomials (sum over SSYT?)

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-functions, young-tableaux

[Hall–Littlewood polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%E2%80%93Littlewood_polynomials) $P_\lambda(x;t)$ is an important deformation of Schur polynomials
forming a basis in the ring of symmetric polynomials over $\mathbb Z[t]$.
There are various definitions, including quite explicit
$$
P_\lambda(x;t)=
\sum_{w\in S_n/\lambda} w\left(x^\lambda\prod_{\lambda_i>\lambda_j}\frac{x_i-tx_j}{x_i-x_j}\right)
$$
but I’m interested in a combinatorial description.

Schur polynomial $s_\lambda$ is a sum of monomials corresponding to semi-standard Young tableux of shape $\lambda$ —
so I'm expecting an answer in the form of a weight on SSYT.

P.S. I'm mostly interested in the principal specialization of H-L polynomials — maybe this $(q,t)$-weight on SSYT is easier to describe than the full answer.

Comment: Наткнулся на твой вопрос и решил уж было, что настал мой звездный час, но потом понял, что за Grigory M. Правильный ответ тебе Миша уже рассказал наверняка, да?

Comment: Pardon my French.

Comment: @IgorMakhlin О, привет. Well, yes and no: there is an explicit description of the $t$-weight $\psi$ in Macdonald's book — but it's complicated and not terribly satisfying. So if you have a better answer, please explain it (here or iRL).

Comment: @IgorMakhlin (И про t-версию Бриона и т.п. мы бы с М.Б. с интересом послушали в какой-то момент.)

Comment: Apparently, I do not have a better answer, although I've spent quite some time trying to come up with some more insightful perspective: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/199629

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I recently worked on a paper regarding just this question (http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.8139). We were generalizing Tokuyama's deformation formula (http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1230129805) for the Schur polynomial, so we used Gelfand-Tsetlin patterns rather than Young tableaux. Tokuyama's original formula is in terms of strict GT patterns, which are in bijection with standard Young tableaux, but extending to the Hall-Littlewood polynomials required using nonstrict GT patterns (which are in bijection with SSYT).

Comment: To me GZ-patterns are as good as SSYT (the bijection is straightforward anyway) — thank you, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to get a combinatorial description using semi-standard augmented fillings, by specializing the combinatorial formula for Macdonald polynomials (see wikipedia on the Macdonald polynomials).

It is also possible to get a formula as sum over SSYT's and the cocharge statistic. This gives the expansion of HL-polys in terms of Schur polynomials.

Comment: Wikipedia page on Macdonald polynomials a) doesn't contain words 'semi-standard' or 'augmented'; b) doesn't give a combinatorial description of Macdonald polynomials — it mentions a description of _transformed_ Macdonald polynomials that uses '_certain_ combinatorial statistics' inv and maj. I guess details can be found in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409538

Comment: ...but extracting something _explicit_ for HL polynomials from that doesn't look like an easy task...

Comment: It depends what you mean by explicit; You can easily write this as a sum over a family of tableaux, with some not-so-difficult combinatorial statistics on said tableaux.